# Arduino based ESC for BLDC motor with FOC

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor

This is my first question here.

Lately I wanted to connect bldc motor to my small 3018 CNC machine so I used this design https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3737505 . While doing this modification I got interested in how such ESC works and wanted to design one myself. So after few hours of reading theory I started drawing my own ESC design.

My work is based of this http://electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut91_sch1.php design.

I modified MOSFETs to be IRF3205 as they can provide 40A to my motor.
I also added current sensors INA240
I left drivers as in original design (IR2101)

I want to run this with Arduino FOC library.

So I'm here to ask more advanced people if I'm missing something here?

Here is what I came up with:
[image]

Comment: You probably only need current sensing on 2 phases, because you can always derive the current in the third.

Comment: @JohnD Thank you for checking this out! You are right, I should be able to derive third phase current. I'll remove it.